# Auto-completion does not work with sudo mount

Tags: mount, sudo, auto-completion

I'm using 12.04.2 and auto-completion for `mount` does not work with `sudo`. If I don't use sudo auto-completion works as expected:

```
$ mount --bind -t devpts /dev/<press tab>
block/      char/       dri/        input/      pts/        .udev/
(...)
bus/        disk/       .initramfs/ net/        snd/        vboxusb/
```

This is very annoying when you have paths like `/media/<uuid>`.
Also this is the only command I have seen that does this: `sudo umount` or `sudo apt-get` works as expected.

So how can I debug the problem/fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions which are situation specific. There are two links, which you can try to fix your system.

[Link 1](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/how-to-autocomplete-commands-preceded.html)

[Link 2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1865538)

Autocomplete works fine for me in sudo. Anyways, one way to work with this until its fixed, is to type the whole command first, and then press `Home` key and add `sudo`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. `complete -cf sudo` makes it work again. Thanks!